# MySQL skip the inserting into database when duplicate data inserting

Tags: php, mysql

### A      B

Apple  Pear
Apple  Pear
Apple  Pear
Orange Apple
Orange Beer
Cinder Punch

Comment: What is exactly the question ?

Comment: duplicate data means account all columns ?

Answer (score 3):

add unique index for (A,B) and try with:

```
INSERT IGNORE (A,B) VALUES (..)
```

You can also try to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
more here: ["INSERT IGNORE" vs "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)